# Проблема с потоками

Tags: многопоточность, java

Нужно распараллелить цикл. На каждой терации цикла выполняется некоторый метод, который сам по себе занимает около 2-х секунд времени на моей машине. Решил распараллелить.
Почему-то получилось так, что "параллельное" время соизмеримо с последовательным временем. Появляется мысль, что цикл не распаралеллен. В чем проблема?

```
    int n = 10;

    int totalStepsNumber = n*n*n;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try{

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("result.txt"));

        ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        List<Maker> makerList = new ArrayList<Maker>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
                for ( int k = 0; k < n; k++ ){

                    makerList.add(new Maker(n, i, j, k));
                    int currentStep = i*n*n + j*n + k + 1;

                    System.out.println(currentStep + "/" + totalStepsNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Future<Double>> res = executer.invokeAll(makerList);

        for ( int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++ ){
            output.println(res.get(i).get());
        }

        executer.shutdown();
        output.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(end-start);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
double res = executer.submit(new Maker(n, i, j, k)).get();
```

`executer.submit()` возвращает объект класса `Future`. Метод `Future.get()` возвращает значение, полученное **после** выполнения задачи. То есть, вы в основном потоке отсылаете задачу в параллельный поток на выполнение, и в основном же потоке, не завершая итерацию цикла, ждёте её завершения. Нужно преобразовать код так, чтобы он не ждал завершения параллельного потока в основном. Попробуйте запустить все потоки и получить их результаты с помощью метода `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`.

[Документация ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

**UPD**
Код будет выглядеть как-то так. На практике не проверял. Разбирайтесь сами.

```
    List<Maker> makers = new LinkedList<Maker>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            for ( int k = 0; k < n; k++ ){
                makers.add(new Maker(n, i, j, k));
            }
        }
    }
    List<Future> futures = executer.invokeAll();
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Future f : futures) {
        results.add(f.get());
    }
```

Comment: только в invokeAll() нужно передавать makers

Comment: А не будет ли быстрее запускать не весь скоп потоков, а по количеству ядер?

Comment: А у вас не запустятся сразу все потоки. Вы же создаёте пул всего на два, поэтому одновременно будут выполняться только два потока, а остальные будут ждать в очереди. И да, если запускать больше потоков, чем ядер у процессора, то ускорения не будет. Хотя, не факт, что потоки, запущенные из JVM мапятся на реальные потоки ОС, а не выстраиваются планировщиком JVM. Впрочем, я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в организации потоков на уровне JVM, поэтому предыдущее предложение может быть полнейшим бредом.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!